# error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token - std :: vector

Tags: c++, vector, std

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct
{
    std :: string latitude;
    std :: string longitude;
} coordinate;

std :: vector <coordinate> previousPoints;

int main ()
{
    coordinate.latitude  = latitude;
    coordinate.longitude = longitude;
    previousPoints.push_back (coordinate);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
anisha@linux-y3pi:~> g++ -Wall demo.cpp
demo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
demo.cpp:14:12: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
demo.cpp:15:12: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
demo.cpp:16:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

What's the point that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an actual variable to be added to your vector:

```
int main ()
{
    coordinate c;
    c.latitude  = latitude;
    c.longitude = longitude;
    previousPoints.push_back (c);
```

Comment: I can't believe this!! wow, sometimes I can be so forgetful, thanks,

Comment: Some programming styles impose certain letter capitalizations to avoid these sorts of issues. For example if you were to **always** name your data types with a leading capital letter and **never** use a leading capital letter for your identifiers you'd've avoided this problem while typing the code in

Comment: YePhlck, I use "camelBack", that couldn't have saved me here ;). @ForEveR Besides this is just a part of reproducible example that I created to post here. So, of course the actual file won't have globals.

Comment: @AnishaKaul `coordinate` should have been `Coordinate`.

Comment: @juanchopanza camelBack style doesn't allow that. I;ll see what more styles are there, though.

Comment: You can prefix your types with a `t_` or something similar to that

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef struct
{
    std :: string latitude;
    std :: string longitude;
} coordinate;
```

`coordinate` is typedef on anonymous struct, not object. You should create object of `coordinate` in your function, or not use `typedef`, i.e.

```
struct coord
{
    std :: string latitude;
    std :: string longitude;
} coordinate;
```

now, `coordinate` is object. And one question, why you type spaces after `std` and after `::`? It's legal, but strange.

Comment: I had tried these both ways, didn't work. The fault has been identified by YePhlck. Space after :: makes the code look "clean" to "me".

Comment: @AnishaKaul Ehm... First way is create object of coordinate in main (YePhlck suggest this way), second way - coordinate is global object of type coord...

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to have globals, so I'd refrain from suggesting this as a solution, TBH

Comment: @YePhIcK Yes, global objects is evil, but sometimes - it's okay, so, i suggest first solution, since OP's code looks like using global object.

Answer (score 1):

```
coordinate.latitude  = latitude;
```

You need an object to access a members of it, but `coordinate` just names a struct. Also on the right hand side you don't have a value... You need something like:

```
coordinate c;
c.latitude  = "120";
c.longitude = "10";
previousPoints.push_back(c);
```